# XPath with not contains and preceding

Tags: xpath

I have some code that is structured like this:

```html
<h1><span id="One"></span><span id="Yellow">One</span></h1>

<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>door</p>
<ul>
<li>Intel CPU</li>
</ul>
<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>AMD CPU</p>
<ul>
<li>Elbrus CPU</li>
</ul>

<h1><span id="One more"></span><span id="Yellow">One more</span></h1>

<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>door</p>
<ul>
<li>Intel II CPU</li>
</ul>
<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>AMD II CPU</p>
<ul>
<li>Elbrus II CPU</li>
</ul>

<h1><span id="Something></span></span><span id="Not Yellow">Something</span></h1>

<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>door</p>
<ul>
<li>Intel III CPU</li>
</ul>
<h2><span id="door"></span><span id="White">door</span></h2>
<p>AMD III CPU</p>
<ul>
<li>Elbrus III CPU</li>
</ul>
```

How could I get the strings, that contain "Intel", "AMD", "ELbrus", after **h1** with **span**, that contains **ID="One*"**, but not after **h1** with **span**, that not contains **ID="One*"** (only in front of him).

EDIT:

How can I get the following strings only:

Intel CPU
AMD CPU
Elbrus CPU

Intel II CPU
AMD II CPU
Elbrus II CPU
 ?

I've used:

//h1/span[not(contains(.,"One"))]/preceding::p[contains(text‌​(),"AMD")]|//h1/span‌​[not(contains(.,"One‌​"))]/preceding::p[co‌​ntains(text(),"Intel‌​")]|//h1/span[not(co‌​ntains(.,"One"))]/pr‌​eceding::p[contains(‌​text(),"Elbrus")]|//‌​h1/span[not(contains‌​(.,"One"))]/precedin‌​g::li[contains(text(‌​),"Intel")]|//h1/spa‌​n[not(contains(.,"On‌​e"))]/preceding::li[‌​contains(text(),"AMD‌​")]|//h1/span[not(co‌​ntains(.,"One"))]/pr‌​eceding::li[contains‌​(text(),"Elbrus")]

but it's not working.

Comment: In your example of selected text, shouldn't `Elbrus III CPU` be `Elbrus II CPU`?

Comment: y're right, thanks, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Elbrus III CPU` should really be `Elbrus II CPU` in your example of selected text, this should work...

```
//text()[(contains(.,'Intel') or contains(.,'AMD') or contains(.,'Elbrus')) and preceding::h1[1][span[contains(@id,'One')]]]
```

Comment: I read in the rules: "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"." and deleted my "thank you" comment. And going to delete all comments ander your answer. Am I right? I'm a rookie here, sorry for these questions)

Comment: @FL.Alx - Yeah it's always good to cleanup comments that aren't going to help future users, but it's not anything to worry about. You definitely won't get in trouble for saying thank you on an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for help and explanations! :)